# Filtering out objects with null or undefined properties

Tags: typescript

I am using the AWS SDK and it looks like a lot of it's objects have members that can be undefined. Example below is for `S3.Object`

```
  export interface Object {
    /**
     * 
     */
    Key?: ObjectKey;
    /**
     * 
     */
    LastModified?: LastModified;
    /**
     * 
     */
    ETag?: ETag;
    /**
     * 
     */
    Size?: Size;
    /**
     * The class of storage used to store the object.
     */
    StorageClass?: ObjectStorageClass;
    /**
     * 
     */
    Owner?: Owner;
  }
```

So when processing a list of these objects, I always have to check at the top of the function if the member is not undefined.

```
objects.map(async (object) => {
    if(object.Key) { 
        return
    }
    ...
}
```

I tried the following but didn't work:

```
const objects = objects.filter(object => object.Key)
```

but the type of `objects` is still `S3.Object` thus making `Key` still `string|undefined`.

I also tried:

```
const objects: {Key: string}[] = objects.filter(object => object.Key)
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Type 'Object[]' is not assignable to type '{ Key: string; }[]'.
  Type 'Object' is not assignable to type '{ Key: string; }'.
    Types of property 'Key' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Is there a way to filter the objects first by this property? I want to remove undefined checking for this property whenever processing `objects`

Comment: `const validKeys = Object.keys(yourObject).filter(k => yourObject[k])`

Comment: @boop_the_snoot I don't want to get the valid keys. I want to not check if the property is `null` or `undefined` by narrowing the type an object of type `Object` (with `Key: string|undefined`) to just Object (with `Key: string`) if after checking, it was proven that `Key` is defined.

Comment: create your own interface / class for S3.Object where key types are defined datatype and then cast s3obj to your interface. like : `const mys3 = S3Obj as unknown as MyS3Obj`.

Comment: or else have a look at [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator), you may use this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a type guard for that:

```
interface S3Object {
    Key?: string;
}

interface MyObject {
    Key: string;
}

function isValidObject(obj: S3Object): obj is MyObject {
    return obj.Key !== undefined;
}

let objs1: S3Object[] = [{Key: ''}, {Key: 'test'}, {}, {}];

let objs2: MyObject[] = objs1.filter(isValidObject);

console.log(objs2);
```

Here `isValidObject` can be used in filter to make the compiler know that filtered items are of type MyObject.

Of course you can remove the `MyObject` interface and replace it by `{Key: string}`

[Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) of this feature.

Comment: Somewhat related, is there a way to define an anonymous type `S3Object with Key:string`?

Comment: The corresponding type would be `S3Object & {Key: string}`